# insert query with a subquery

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

i tried to use the following query to insert data in a table and got an error

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
select person_id
from filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr
where fps.song_id = fs.song_id
  and fps.role_id = fr.role_id
  and fps.person_id = 43629;
```

ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

i have specified the fields exactly..

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to insert **one** value in each row, but you have specified **three** columns to be written to:

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
select person_id
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

You will need to list values for all of the three columns in your select statement. The following might work:

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
select fps.person_id, fs.song_id, fr.role_id
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only selecting `person_id` from the subquery, whereas you specified `person_id`, `song_id` and `role_id` in the insert clause. You must select also the missing fields in the subquery.

You probably want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
SELECT
    person_id,
    song_id,
    role_id
FROM 
    filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr
WHERE
    fps.song_id = fs.song_id
AND
    fps.role_id = fr.role_id
AND
   fps.person_id = 43629;
```

Answer (score 2):

you're just specifying one field ( `select person_id` ) to insert into the table, while the column specifications state that `person_id`, `sond_id` *and* `role_id` will be inserted.

this should work better:

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
select person_id, fs.song_id, fr.role_id
from filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr
where fps.song_id = fs.song_id
  and fps.role_id = fr.role_id
  and fps.person_id = 43629;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
select person_id, fs.song_id, fr.role_id
from filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr
where fps.song_id = fs.song_id
  and fps.role_id = fr.role_id
  and fps.person_id = 43629;
```

Answer (score 1):

Subquery return values must match with insert query as below.

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id) 
    select person_id, song_id, role_id 
    from filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr 
    where fps.song_id = fs.song_id 
      and fps.role_id = fr.role_id 
      and fps.person_id = 43629;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking it to add values for 3 columns (person_id, song_id, role_id), but are only supplying 1:

person_id

Try:

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id)
values (select person_id
from filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr
where fps.song_id = fs.song_id
  and fps.role_id = fr.role_id
  and fps.person_id = 43629);
```

or:

```
insert into filmo_person_song (person_id, song_id, role_id)
values (
select person_id, song_id, role_id
from filmo_person_song fps, filmo_song fs, filmo_role fr
where fps.song_id = fs.song_id
  and fps.role_id = fr.role_id
  and fps.person_id = 43629);
```